# AdColony only Showing Test Ads

Tags: android, adcolony

I've integrated adcolony into my app, but only shows Test ADS
I already turned into Live and doesn't show anything.

What I need to do?
I think they will start showing after certain number of requests, am I right?

Comment: You could improve this question slightly by including the programming language / SDK you are using to develop your app. It is probably Java here, and I'm assuming that with my 'onRequestNotFilled' comment below (but it may also be a Cordova/Phonegap app as I am about to give this a try with AdColony too). If' it's Java and the standard AdColony Java SDK for Android, it might help to mention that (and tag Java).

Answer (score 1):

If this refers to not receiving an ad at all to show, i.e. getting `onRequestNotFilled` invoked, then I ran into this earlier tonight and I think I found the answer.

On [this page](https://support.adcolony.com/helpdesk/web-dashboard-publisher-apps-zones-setup/) in "Step 3" they say:

> New video zones automatically default to receive test ads. Please note that **if you set your zone to receive live ads before your application is live on a user-facing marketplace with AdColony included, it may not receive any ads.** When finished, click the green button labeled “Save” to save your zone settings.

Note the sentence I have bolded (second one) in that paragraph.

I'm intepreting this as meaning you can't just test this on the Android emulator or other simulation, but I'm not clear at what point your application "is live on a user-facing marketplace with AdColony included". I hope this doesn't mean published on Google Play or the AppStore.  But it seems the answer is this is intentional. If I contact their support for a clarification, I will post an update.

Comment: Did you contact the support?

Comment: @BuntuLinux I don't really remember, it was 2 years ago, but I don't think I got around to using it. (Another project became the priority instead.) I just accepted that I could only get test ads in the test zone and I wouldn't be able to test live until I deployed live.